# Context menu start in Private Browser

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, context-menu, opera

Is there any way to start a browser (i.e: firefox, chrome, opera, etc) in private/incognito mode without having to open the browser? There are methods that exist to configure the browser to start in private mode but I dont want to force it, rather just allow for the option to start in private mode (such as right click > open in Private mode).

Answer (score 1):

This feature did exist but was removed from Firefox some time ago, see [here](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2734967) and [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=856839). Alternatively you could use two profiles with Firefox, one regular profile and one profile without history (which is not exactly the same as private mode I think, for instance tracking protection would not work). It is possible to select the profile via command line, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiple_profiles).

Answer (score 0):

Didn't tried all, but at least Chrome and IE in Windows 7, if you place a shortcut at tasks bar, it allow you to right click icon and open incognito directly.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on task bar icon -> Open incognito mode

[image]